# Trying to send ETH from Mist Wallet to Poloniex, received ETC instead

Tags: mist, cpp-ethereum, ethereum-classic, poloniex

I want to send both my ETC and ETH to Poloniex.

I have a basic understanding of the DAO fork and know nothing about programming. I googled something about a replay attack and using a split contract. I also read about how Poloniex or Kraken automatically splits the currency for you. All the information is about two months old and I'm afraid it might not be applicable in the present.

So I sent 1 Eth directly to Poloniex just to be sure. When I checked Etherscan it said that my transaction was processed in the Ethereum Classic Blockchain. My ETH balance on Etherscan is unchanged but 1 ETC (plus tx fee) was missing from the ETC balance and I have 1 ETC credited to Poloniex.

What do I do? Do I send out all the ETC from Mist to Polo, since it seems I am in no danger of losing the equivalent amount of ETH? Will I be able to finally send out ETH once I have emptied the account of ETC. I assume it will not be as simple as that.

Other pertinent information:

- I am using (I assume the latest) version 0.8.4 of Mist that is not completely synced at the moment. I read that it's supposed to ask me if should go on the old blockchain or the new, which it hasn't yet. I assume it has something to do with it.
- The ETH and ETC are orignally of equal amount
- The funds are from the pre-sale wallet, which I am only accessing now.

Comment: Just to confirm, this is the first transaction youve attempted to send from this wallet since the hard fork (July 2016)? If so, I would say the TX on the eth chain is stuck due to the attacks on the network or its stuck due the fact you haven't synced 100% yet. I would say wait and sync and see if it goes thru.

Comment: I think it's the network attacks. I got both my eth and etc on polo all safe and sound now :)